# Overloading & upcasting Java

Tags: java, oop

Could someone explain why while upcasting when we have varargs in parent class, the method of parent class executes instead-of child's one?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
        a.foo("123");
    }

}

class A {
    public void foo(String... s) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void foo(String s) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Could someone explain how it works?

Comment: method foo in B does not override method from A actually, they have different arguments, make habit to always use `@Override` on methods in children to ask compiler to validate this

Comment: The compiler looks at the type of `a` and figures out that you want a method `foo(String s)`, because that's what's in class `A`.  The method in `B` doesn't override this, because its signature is different.

Comment: Guys, there is no overriding allowed, it's all about overloading. So these answers cannot be right.

Comment: @Artur: you call `foo` on a reference on type `A`, so only methods of type `A` are considered as candidates. Only overriding can do runtime polymorphism, overloading only matters when all potential methods are accessible on the type we call the method on, which is not the case here.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, so why then if both methods of classes A and B have the same signature 'String s', the foo() from B executes?

Comment: ```class A {
    public void foo(String s) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void foo(String s) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}```

Comment: here foo() from class B works

Comment: Because then overriding happens. Overriding: same method & compatible signatures in different classes. Overloading: same *name*, different signatures in same (or different) classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of a variable defines the interface you can use to interact with the object it's referring to. In this case, you are referring to a `B` instance through a variable of type `A`. Because `A` has only the varargs version of `foo()`, only this one is available for the compiler to choose.